# Why does the Tour page have a ridiculous example as a question?

Tags: discussion

The tour page of the site has Unicorns and Daisies as a sample question. Why?

Shouldn't there be an Islam related question as an example?

[image]

Comment: @goldPseudo I think its a bug since Unicorns is a Meta Meme and has come into the pciture accidently. It would be better if the Community or the devs decide whether its a bug or not rather than you removing it single handedly. :)

Comment: the [tag:bug] tag "indicates you've found an erroneous or unexpected behaviour in the system that needs to be fixed."  You've indicated nothing to suggest that this behaviour is either erroneous or unexpected, or what if any "fix" needs to be done; you're asking *why* something *is*, which would put this clearly into [tag:discussion] or [tag:support], *not* [tag:bug].

Comment: My bad. Its not a bug. I made the edit before you answered. Should a new question on changing it be opened? Since Unicorns give even worse impression of the site. @goldPseudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a default example question across the network; there is an option to choose an actual on-site question as an example, but there are [certain system-enforced criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163947/132874) as to which questions may be chosen.

Right now, *very* few of our questions meet those criteria (As of this post, there are literally only *two*: [Can we pray after sex if we didn't ejaculate?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9896/22) and [When should one stop eating and drinking? And what is the ruling on one who has the vessel in his hand when hearing the adhaan?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1905/22)), and in my personal opinion neither of these are sufficiently high-quality to use as an example of the sort of participation we want to encourage here.

Comment: How about this question? http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/215/was-the-prophet-sinless

Comment: As of this post, the two questions I linked are literally the *only* ones that meet the criteria.

Comment: well is there any way to break the rules, i.e. not according to that of the Data explorer query, but rather decide here based on voting election. You know, just shortlist some good questions of the site and then run a voting. Plz inquire if this possible

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser Our best answers are typically long and reference-heavy and that would just make the tour page too complex, I think.  This is been a long-standing feature request on MSE for a while; it's a similar problem again with e.g. Skeptics and other such reference-heavy sites.  You're free to open up your own [tag:feature-request] on the topic though.